# Canvas drawing not loading in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I need to generate snapshots for seo. 
I am using puppeteer(headless chrome) for this purpose. 
On main page i have a canvas, on which i start to draw once the component has mounted (my main site is in react).

Issue is that when i get the html from puppeteer, the drawing on the canvas is not there.

In puppeteer code i wait till the content is not loaded.

```
html = await page.content()
```

How can i make puppeteer wait till the point canvas is not painted.

Comment: Do you want to wait until something happens or do you want to get the image from the Canvas? Because you cannot read the image from the canvas via `page.content`. This will only return HTML code.

Comment: Something is drawn on the canvas, i tried waiting for some 20 seconds, but still i am not able to get what is drawn on the canvas, Though in headless chrome I am able to see the drawing on the canvas. Seems like puppeteer simply replicates the html.

Comment: Added an answer that shows you how to get the image shown in the canvas :)

Comment: Show us how you do get your snapshot.

Answer (score 6):

`page.content` will only return the HTML representation of the DOM. To get the actual image of a canvas inside the DOM, you can use the function [`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). This will return the image that is shown in a base64-encoded string.

**Code sample**

```js
const dataUrl = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas-selector");
    return canvas.toDataURL();
});

// dataUrl looks like this: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw..."
const base64String = dataUrl.substr(dataUrl.indexOf(',') + 1); // get everything after the comma
const imgBuffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64'); // 
fs.writeFileSync('image.png', imgBuffer);
```

The `evaluate` call will return the base64 encoded buffer of the image. You need to first remove the `"data:...,"` from that and then you can put that into a buffer. The buffer can then be saved (or handled in any other way).

Comment: That's not what the question asks for at all.

Comment: @Kaiido See the comments where I asked for clarification above. He is saying "I am not able to get what is drawn on the canvas". I added a sentence regarding the `page.content`, though.

Comment: @Kaiido For clarification: I read the question as "I am using page.content trying to get the image of a canvas".

Comment: I read it as "I want to take a snapshot of my page, which does also contain a canvas drawing".

Comment: @ThomasDondorf Is there way to create image with white background. ?